# Stop netcat as soon as grep matches something

Tags: grep, pipe, netcat, timeout

I am facing a problem using netcat in a `bash` script.

I would like to match a specific output after sending a command and continue the script execution as soon as possible (not waiting for a netcat timeout)

```
$> echo 'my_command' | nc -q 10 <IP> <PORT> | grep -m 1 EXPECTED_OUTPUT
# ISSUE: Closes the connection quite instantly
$> echo $?
$> 1 # grep did not get (yet) the output of nc
```

Another try:

```
$> echo 'my_command' | nc -w 1 <IP> <PORT> | grep -m 1 EXPECTED_OUTPUT
Binary file (standard input) matches
# ISSUE: Wait until the timeout expires
$> echo $?
$> 0
```

For information:

without command, netcat prints a banner message:

```
$>nc <IP> <PORT>                                                                                        
welcome message
```

I am not against other tools (`telnet`, ...)

I would like a `bash`-compliant solution.

As the expected message should come within a second I use the timeout `-w 1` of `nc`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You want to set it up so that `nc` is killed as soon as `grep` finishes. Here is one way:

```
( subshell_pid=$BASHPID ; echo 'my_command' | nc $IP $PORT > >(grep -m 1 EXPECTED_OUTPUT ; kill -13 -- -$subshell_pid ; ) )
```

This all runs in a subshell, and then kills all processes started by the subshell when `grep` finishes.

The `>()` is [process substitution](http://tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/process-sub.html), which lets you pipe from one command to multiple commands.

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer and the SIGPIPE reminder; Your proposal is pretty much what I'm using.
I upvoted and will accept your answer in a few days unless someone proposes something more 'straight forward'